# Find a complex potential function for the given complex potential function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\tilde{\chi} = z^{2} -iz + 3$ and use the following theorem to define a new complex potential function $\chi$ such that the unit circle is a streamline:

Theorem: Let $\tilde{\chi}$ be a complex potential function such that any of its singularity occurs outside $B_{a}\left(0\right)$, then the new complex potential function
$$
\chi := \tilde{\chi}\left(z\right)+ \overline{\tilde{\chi}\left(\frac{a^{2}}{\overline{z}}\right)}
$$
has the same singularities as $\tilde{\chi}\left(z\right)$ outside the the ball  of radius $a$ centered at $0$ and the circle which is the boundary of this ball is a streamline.

Im a pure math major and this seems to be a physics application I am unfamiliar with. Our complex analysis prof. is doing more of a physics applications course. So is my $a = 1$ as I'm working with $S^{1}\ ?$ Can anybody help me?? So do I just plug and chug for this problem or?

Comment: I agree that you should put $a=1$. And then I guess as you said you plug in $\tilde\chi$ into the equation to get $\chi$.

Comment: so I end up with $z^2+\frac{1}{\overline{z}^2}+6-i(z-\frac{1}{\overline{z}})$ @Ramanujan ?

Comment: Yes, me too. But that's just how I interpreted the task...